# Do I add my ability modifier to the damage of the bonus-action attack granted by the Crossbow Expert feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, attack

The [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) rule says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand. **You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.**
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon,
>   instead of making a melee attack with it.

With Two-Weapon Fighting, I can only add my ability modifier to the damage of the first attack. Even if I get the [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dual-wielder) feat (PHB, p. 165), it doesn't say anything about adding the ability score to the damage.

The [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert) feat (PHB, p. 165) says:

> Thanks to extensive practice with the crossbow, you gain the following
>   benefits:
>
> - You ignore the loading quality of crossbows with which you are proficient.
> - Being within 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn’t impose disadvantage
>     on your ranged attack rolls.
> - When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon,
>     you can use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you
>     are holding.

**When I attack using the bonus action granted by Crossbow Expert, do I add my ability modifier to the damage?** I don't know whether I should follow the *Two-Weapon Fighting* rules, or roll damage as for a normal weapon attack.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It looks like you're asking about the [5th edition of D&D](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules), can you confirm that for us?

Comment: Looks good now! I've made a few edits to add links and page numbers and clean things up. It should be reopened shortly. I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked before! I searched RPG.SE and found no questions that ask quite what this one does.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate (though the answer there might answer this one): [Does Crossbow Expert override the light weapon requirement for Two Weapon Fighting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132812/does-crossbow-expert-override-the-light-weapon-requirement-for-two-weapon-fighti)

Comment: Also related: [Does the double bladed scimitar's special attack let you use your ability modifier for the damage of the attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141645/does-the-double-bladed-scimitars-special-attack-let-you-use-your-ability-modifi/141648#141648)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### You can add your ability modifier to damage from the bonus action attack

The general rule for [damage rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageRolls) is:

> When attacking with a weapon, you add your ability modifier--the same modifier used for the attack roll--to the damage.

In short: **You can add your ability modifier to your crossbow attack because nothing tells you that you cannot.**

[Unofficial guidance from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/727575357868539905) (5e's lead rules designer), which some may consider authoritative, agrees with this interpretation:

> When making a weapon attack, you add your ability modifier to the damage, unless a feature tells you not to.

**So far, so good.**

But, does this rule for [two-weapon fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting), which also grants a bonus action, confuse matters?

> You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

Dont worry - this rule can be safely ignored. **The bonus action granted by the Crossbow Expert feat is not the same as the bonus action granted by two-weapon fighting**. Thus the two-weapon fighting rules are completely irrelevant to your situation.

Comment: This also follows from the general rule philosophy of 5e - "There are no hidden rules".  Two-Weapon Fighting and Crossbow Expert describe what they do in full - no 'hidden' rules about one would exist in the other.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes, because it's not Two-Weapon Fighting.

As you correctly point out, the rules for using a hand crossbow with Crossbow Expert don't mention losing out on your stat bonus. Since using your off-hand crossbow in this way doesn't actually use the Two-Weapon Fighting rules, you don't need to refer to them at all when using Crossbow Expert.

Since Crossbow Expert effectively gives you an entirely new way of spending your bonus action to attack, you get your full ability modifier to damage.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct but they fail to explicitly state the factor that makes them correct: The rules for 2-weapon style do not apply in this case because they only apply to *melee* weapons.  The only way that the rules for dual weapon could apply to your hand crossbow would be if you swung the crossbow itself at somebody as an improvised club.

So long as you are using the crossbow as a *ranged* weapon to fire crossbow bolts at enemies, the 2 weapon style rule does not apply and you only need to worry about the rules of the feat that allows you to fire it as a bonus action.

Comment: I normally don't care, but in this case I am curious why somebody downvoted this answer.  Is this an actual disagreement with my interpretation of the rules?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I also didn't upvote because while you are very right, you didn't support it with the relevant rules citations. TIggerous kind of addresses it in their last sentence.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in this case the relevant rules are quoted in the actual question.

Comment: DuckTapeAl also covers this,so I'm not sure that it's exlicitly not covered in their answer. But even then, I usually reference "as you've quoted" in answers that have the relevant quotes in the question (I didn't upvote Al's answer either because of this, too.) But you asked, and I answered. How you want to proceed is up to you :) - although i don't know why someone downvoted.

Comment: "The other answers [...] fail to explicitly state the factor that makes them correct: The rules for 2-weapon style do not apply in this case because they only apply to melee weapons." - The TWF rules are irrelevant not because of the weapon type that the feat lets you make a bonus-action attack with - but because the feat is what's letting you make that bonus-action attack, not TWF. Even if the feat let you make a bonus-action attack with a specific melee weapon (e.g. a spear), it still wouldn't relate to TWF, because the feat is what grants you the ability to make that attack, not TWF.

Comment: @V2Blast Your comment suggests that the 2 weapon style could apply if the character did not have that feat, which is clearly false.  2 weapon style can never apply to a hand crossbow except in the unlikely case that the character tries to use it as an improvised melee weapon.

Comment: @krb: Uh... my comment doesn't suggest that at all.

Comment: I agree with V2Blast here. As you say in your answer, this attack doesn't meet the criteria for TWF - that's fine and true. But, even if you could silmultaeneously meet the criteria for two different types of bonus action attack, you still wouldn't then need to apply both sets of related rules to that one bonus action attack - you'd decide which of the two bonus actions you were taking and then apply either one or the other set of rules.

Comment: So, TWF rules don't apply here, not because it *doesn't* meet the criteria to be classed as a TWF bonus action attack, but because it *does* meet the criteria to be a bonus action CE attack -- and that's kind of attack the player has chosen to make.

Comment: Yeah, I think that V2Blast mean is that it doesn't matter if it's a ranged or melee weapon. In this special feat is ranged, but hypothetically speaking if there was a feat just like this with a melee weapon instead the same rule would apply because the bonus action is not the TWF action but the feat itself.